# Using ExtJs in Angular 2/4

Tags: angular, extjs

I am trying to include the ExtJs Library in the Angular 2 application . I saw in SenchaCon they are working on for a plugin but no more updates since a year.

Are there any examples available to integrate version 6.0 with Angualr application? Please help.

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? What have you tried?

Comment: There is no library available for extjs to be used in angular 2. so trying to get if any other ways to do that.